# Copy file based on flavor at the start of Android gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two flavors in the gradle file for an Android app:

```
productFlavors {
    production { }
    devel { }
}
```

I have a configuration file that I need to copy to the `app/` directory before any other tasks run when building the project. The is a configuration file per flavor, i.e.:

```
etc/configuration-production.json
etc/configuration-devel.json
```

When building `devel` I need to do essentially this:

```
cp etc/configuration-devel.json app/configuration.json
```

When building `production`:

```
cp etc/configuration-production.json app/configuration.json
```

How do I automate this in gradle? This copy needs to happen first and foremost when executing a build since some of the tasks need that `app/configuration.json` file to be there.

I tried:

```
task copyConfig(type: Copy) {
     from "etc/configuration-${Flavor.name}.json"
     into "app/configuration.json"
} 

build.dependsOn copyConfig
```

But didn't work. The `copyConfig` task didn't run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following to your `app` `build.gradle` for copying your file from `etc/configuration-XXX.json` to `app/configuration.json` in the first statement of the respective tasks `assembleDevel.*` & `assembleProduction.*` :

```
def cp(copyType) {
    println "copying " + "../etc/configuration-" + copyType + ".json"
    copy {
        from "../etc/configuration-" + copyType + ".json"
        into '.'
        rename { String fileName ->
            fileName.replace("configuration-" + copyType + ".json", "configuration.json")
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name ==~ /assembleDevel.*/) {
        task.doFirst() {
            cp("devel")
        }
    } else if (task.name ==~ /assembleProduction.*/) {
        task.doFirst() {
            cp("production")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the required configuration :

```
app/
├── build.gradle
etc/
├── configuration-production.json
└── configuration-devel.json
```

If `assembleDevel.*`/`assembleProduction.*` are not the tasks you are looking for, you can replace them with for instance : `prepareDevel.*Dependencies`/`prepareProduction.*Dependencies`

Comment: Thanks! Added a more generic approach with regex based on your solution.

Comment: I've added match for dynamic build type with regex as you suggested